# Why does my Visual Studio 2022 scroll in chunks

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I just recently installed Visual Studio 2022 and when scrolling through my code or anything inside visual studio it does it bit by bit. For some reason the scrolling isn't smooth and it just jumps down a certain amount of lines. Why does it do this?

Comment: Maybe your computer is not powerful enough and VS needs to swap a lot of times.

Comment: Go to `Tools > Options > Text Editor > Advanced > Scrolling Sensitivity`. Maybe you have high values set here. My settings are - Vertical: 3 and Horizontal: 1.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ShawnOrr NO. The problem is not if it scrolls 1 or 3 lines,but it scrolls an entire screen at once

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that Visual Studio has always been like this. I just usually am working on a bigger screen and never noticed that it scrolls the way it does. I decreased the scrolling sensitivity as some suggested and it helped a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "Smooth Scroll Plugin" + "JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly
v5.1.20230514" On the Visual Studio Extensions Store For VSC and VS 2022 can help.

Comment: **It works with VS2019 too

Answer (score 0):

Just turn off the following settings. And VS 2022 poor scrolling experience will be improved.

[image]